# Creating a matrix using brackets

Tags: matrices

How to write this in latex:

[image]

The closest I've come to it, is this:

```
\{\begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{matrix}\}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! The manual of `amsmath` tells you to use `\begin{Bmatrix}...\end{Bmatrix}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `amsmath` `Bmatrix`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
   \begin{Bmatrix} 
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
   \end{Bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Other types are:

1. `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}` without brackets
2. `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` with parentheses brackets
3. `\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}` with brackets
4. `\begin{vmatrix}...\end{vmatrix}` with vertical bar brackets
5. `\begin{Vmatrix}...\end{Vmatrix}` with double vertical bar brackets
6. `\begin{Bmatrix}...\end{Bmatrix}` with curly brackets as shown at top

Another workaround is to use `\left...\right` option.

```latex
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{matrix}
\right\}
```

This could prove helpful when typing things like open-triangle close-vertical (`<a|`) braces etc.