# Matrices Latex Curly Bracket

Tags: math-mode

I was trying to write an equation using curly bracket matrices. So, it would be something like below:

[image]

I figured out how to write one matrix with curly brackets.

```
\[
   \begin{Bmatrix} 
      \Delta x \\ 
       \Delta y \\ 
       \Delta z \\
       \Delta \dot{x} \\
       \Delta \dot{y} \\
       \Delta \dot{z}
   \end{Bmatrix}
\]
```

However, I don't know how to fix it so I have a matrix is equal to another one.
Thanks!

For reference, I used this link: [Creating a matrix using brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342448/creating-a-matrix-using-brackets)

Comment: Please provide a fully contained example, no external links if possible, and certainly no screenshotted code ... also, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @Ingmar would you say this is better? Sorry my first time posting code.

Comment: Explain clearly what issue you have exactly to make two equal matrices. Please add a minimal working example (MWE),  as in the answer on your link, compilable "as is", showing your best attempt with two matrices, then  explain clearly what is still wrong.  To contruct your picture the code is just `\[`  *one Bmatrix* `_{T{1}} = \left[\Phi\right]`  *another Bmatrix* `_{T{pf}} \] `

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of the column vector encased in curly braces looks fine. Since it occurs twice, it's useful to create a little macro for it and to call this shortcut macro, say, `\curlyvec`.

To provide an extra touch of fine math typesetting, I suggest encasing the `T_1` subscript of the first curly-braces vector in a `\mathrlap` directive. This makes the subscript protrude to the right without messing up the spacing around the `=` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathrlap' macro
\newcommand\curlyvec{%
   \begin{Bmatrix} 
       \Delta x \\ 
       \Delta y \\ 
       \Delta z \\
       \Delta \dot{x} \\
       \Delta \dot{y} \\
       \Delta \dot{z}
   \end{Bmatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\curlyvec_{\mathrlap{{\!T_1}}} = [\Phi] \curlyvec_{\!T_{\mathrm{pf}}} 
\]

\end{document}
```